# How do I set column name with current date in SQLite Database Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I m creating an attendance app in Android using SQLite Database  . I want 
For that I have Name as one column and rest of the columns I want dates as 01/09/2016,02/09/2016,03/09/2016,04/09/2016,05/09/2016 etc..as column names of [type varchar (Yes or no)] 
, so that I can fill every row by yes or no . 
Can anyone tell me how can I implement this ?

Note : Daily app has to add current date as column in SQLite database.

Comment: that sounds like a horribly bad design. Why can't you have a child table  with `date` and `value` columns? sqlite has a 2000 column limit on a table. what are you going to do in ~5.5 years when you hit that max?

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand .

Comment: Google for "database normalization" and start reading.

Comment: @MarcB some don't believe in long term relationships . :p